# Unable to import class files in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to learn Kotlin so I am just starting out. I have two files, the main file and a class file. I declared my package in the class file, then imported the class in the main file. However, when I try to run the program, the compiler says I have a reference error.

main.kt:

```
package test.app
import test.app.Rectangle

fun main() {
    val rectangle = Rectangle(6.0, 5.0)
    println(rectangle.perimeter)
}
```

Rectangle.kt:

```
package test.app

class Rectangle(var length: Double, var height: Double) {
    var perimeter = (length + height) * 2
}
```

This is probably a simple issue, however I am not experienced enough in Kotlin to find a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is fine! Make sure you updated kotlin plugin with latest version. And your IDE is up to date.

[image: Everything is fine. Make sure you updated kotlin plugin with latest version]